# RTCPeerConnection.ontrack event not firing

Tags: javascript, webrtc

Getting my feet wet with WebRTC and running into a problem with the RTCPeerConnection.ontrack event not firing whenever a new MediaStreamTrack object has been created (by the RTCPeerConnection.addTrack() function).

Using the textbook WebRTC getUserMedia example, I grab a single stream from my laptop's camera which I set as the srcObject for one  element (local) when the Start button is clicked.  When the Call button is clicked, I use the addTrack method on the grabbed stream, which I hold in the global localStream variable.  At this point the globally defined ontrack event handler should fire and give me the second video, right?  No dice, though.

I was able to get this to work with addStream and onaddstream - but both have been removed from the latest WebRTC spec and are not supported by the most recent versions of Chrome and FireFox.

Pic and script attached - any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

[Pic with Web Console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBkgW.jpg)

```
'use strict';

var localStream;
var yourVideo = document.querySelector('#yours');
var theirVideo = document.querySelector('#theirs');
var callBtn = document.querySelector('#callBtn');
var startBtn = document.querySelector('#startBtn');
startBtn.onclick = hasUserMedia;
callBtn.onclick = call;

var cfg = null;
var pc1 = new RTCPeerConnection(cfg);
var pc2 = new RTCPeerConnection(cfg);

pc1.ontrack = function(e){
    console.log("ontrack fired!");
    theirVideo.srcObject = e.streams[0];
}

function hasUserMedia(){
  console.log("entering hasUserMedia()...");
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true, audio: false}).then(function(stream){

    localStream = stream;
    console.log("stream val: " + localStream);

    yourVideo.srcObject = stream;

  });
}

function call(){
  console.log("stream  val @ call(): " + localStream);
  localStream.getTracks().forEach(track => pc1.addTrack(track, localStream));
}
```

---

index.html

```
<html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Learning WebRTC - Chapter 4: Creating a
        RTCPeerConnection</title>
        <style>
            body {
            background-color: #3D6DF2;
            margin-top: 15px;
            }
            video {
            background: black;
            border: 1px solid gray;
            }
            #container {
            position: relative;
            display: block;
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: 500px;
            height: 500px;
            }
            #yours {
            width: 150px;
            height: 150px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 15px;
            right: 15px;
            }
            #theirs {
            width: 500px;
            height: 500px;
            }
        </style>
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="container">
        <video id="yours" autoplay></video>
        <video id="theirs" autoplay></video>
        <button id="startBtn">Start</button>
        <button id="callBtn">Call</button>
        </div>
        <script src="https://webrtc.github.io/adapter/adapter-latest.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="main.js"></script>
      </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Tip: Use [adapter.js](https://github.com/webrtc/adapter) to polyfill `ontrack` in Chrome. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/aynr0k5q/

Comment: Updated that jsfiddle to use `addTrack` instead of `addStream` https://jsfiddle.net/p6d49haj/

Answer (score 3):

Both Firefox and Chrome still support onaddstream. Chrome does not yet support addTrack, you can still use addStream (despite Firefox complaining).

Your script is missing the exchange of SDP and ICE candidates for ontrack to fire as well.

Check https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/pc1/ for a complete and working example.

Answer (score 2):

[addTrack on Chromium Issue Tracker](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=642712)

[addTrack is blocked by RTCRtpSender and RTCRtpReceiver extensions to RTCPeerConnection](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5347809238712320)

Answer (score 1):

I got into the same problem while trying to implement a video chat, but I found a fix. The fix is simple; make sure to add the `ontrack` event, `onicecandidate` and the video stream object at the creation of the `rtcpeerconnection`. See the code below

```
var configuration = {
offerToReceiveAudio: true,
offerToReceiveVideo: true
}
var peerConn  = new RTCPeerConnection(cofiguration);
peerConn.ontrack = gotStream;
peerConn.onicecandidate = gotIceCandidate;
peerConn.addStream(localStream);

//and do the rest your style... Hope this helps.
```